# Prove that $f(x)=3\sin⁡(3\pi \ x/4)\ + \ 2 \cos(\pi \ x/3)$ is neither odd or even function

Tags: functions, proof-verification, parity

I  know $f(x)$  is neither even or odd if $f (-x)  \ne -f (x)$  and $f (-x)  \ne f (x)$

This is what I have done so far. 
$$f(x)=3 \sin⁡(\pi x/4)+2 \cos⁡(\pi x/3)$$
$$\begin{align}
f(-x)&=3 \sin⁡(-3πx/4)+2 \cos⁡(-πx/3) \\
&=-3 \sin⁡(3πx/4)+2 \cos⁡(-\pi x/3)\\         
\end{align}$$

$$f (-x)\ne f (x),\quad f(-x) \ne f (x)$$

Is the solution sufficient for a full proof?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct idea, but you can improve on the way to present it.

$f(-x)=-3\sin(3\pi x/4)+2\cos(\pi x /3)$

On the one hand, $g(x)=f(-x)+f(x)=4\cos(\pi x /3)$, and since $g(0) \neq 0$ we have $g(x) \neq 0$ and therefore f is not odd.

On the other hand, $h(x)=f(x)-f(-x)=6\sin(3\pi x/4)$, and since $h(1) \neq 0$ we have $h(x) \neq 0$ and therefore f is not even.

Comment: Welcome! I edited only to clean up a bit of formatting. For example, `\cos x` : $\cos x$, and similarly for $\sin x$ = `\sin x`.  Click on the link for more information on using [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thanks, it makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove it, you need only one counterexample, and the simple case $x=\pm1$ suffices.